# Mapbox: Display multiple styleURLs at the same time on a MGLStyle (create layer using styleURL)

Tags: swift, mapbox

I am trying to add multiple styles to a Mapbox `MGLMapView`. I understand this is not directly possible as `MGLMapView.style` only takes a single `styleURL` so I have been trying to get around this by adding a layer to the style using a `styleURL`.

A little explanation of why:

As shown in the [Mapbox offline maps docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/mobile-offline/) you can only download an `MGLTilePyramidOfflineRegion` using a `styleURL`. However, later I want to be able to display multiple of these offline regions at the same time (regions with different URLs). The urls I am currently are for a satellite, hybrid, and property line. I would like to be able to show the property line map on top of either the satellite or hybrid map. Currently, I can only show one at a time changing the `MGLMapView.style.styleURL`.

What I have tried:

```
guard let layer = (notification.userInfo?["layer"])! as? Layer,
      let url = layer.url,
      let style = mapView.style
else { return }

switch layer.id {
    case .initial, .satellite:
        mapView.styleURL = url
        break
    case .property:

       // 1)
       let source = MGLRasterTileSource(identifier: "\(layer.identifier)Style", configurationURL: URL)
       let layer = MGLRasterStyleLayer(identifier: "\(layer.identifier)Layer", source: source)

       // 2)
       let source = MGLVectorTileSource(identifier: "\(layer.identifier)Style", configurationURL: URL)
       let layer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "\(layer.identifier)Layer", source: source)

       // When testing either 1 or 2 is commented out
       style.addSource(source)
       style.insertLayer(layer, at: UInt(style.layers.count - 1))
}
```

Supporting code:

```
enum LayerType: Int64 {
    case hybrid = 0
    case satellite = 1
    case property = 2
}

struct Layer {
    var id: LayerType
    var identifier: String
    var name: String
    var url: URL?
}

let layers = [
    Layer(id: .hybrid, identifier: "hybrid", name: "Hybrid", url: URL(string: "mapbox://styles/XXX")),
    Layer(id: .satellite, identifier: "sat", name: "Satellite", url: URL(string: "mapbox://styles/XXX")),
    Layer(id: .property, identifier: "property", name: "Property", url: URL(string:  "mapbox://styles/XXX"))
]
```

Is there any other way to show two downloaded maps at the same time when they have different URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add these layers to your style in Mapbox Studio? At runtime you can toggle them on and off, as described in the below example:

https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/runtime-toggle-layer/

This would allow you to download the offline region that includes all layers.

Comment: I have a hybrid style, a satellite style, and a parcel style. I was hoping to be able to toggle the parcel style on top of either the satellite or hybrid style, This would save me from having to create a hybrid, satellite, hybrid-parcel, and satellite-parcel styles.

Comment: The problem is the offline cache, which for one region can only be of a specific style. Also, to my knowledge it is not possible to display 2 styles at the same time in one map.